# Converting WMS services into vector data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, vector, arcscan

I have a WMS service which is distributed by the national organisation of my country. However, I want to process these data, but it's impossible due to WMS service is provided as a map.

Can I find any tool which allows me to convert the WMS service into vector data?

I have tried to export the WMS service into PNG image, specifying color mode as 1-bit Monochrome Threshold, in order to use it subsequently at arcScan tool.

However, the image which is extracted does not contain anything.

Is there any explanation?

Comment: Be careful when doing this that you do not infringe on copyright of the mapping provider by trying to capture their maps as vector. You should check first that they do not offer a vector service before trying to rasterise as @MappaGnosis suggests in the answer below!

Answer (score 3):

By definition, [WMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) will return raster (image) data.  You need to test your data provider's server with a [GetCapabilities](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) request to see if it offers [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) (Web Feature Service) which will give you vector data (the documentation there is for geoserver so edit the path suitably).  That is the first thing I would do before trying to mess about with converting rasters to vectors (which will be nasty at best).

If you data provider does not expose WFS then, I would see if there is an alternative means of accessing the vector data.  In short, I would try every avenue first before trying to convert the rasters to vectors.  The results you get will be very dependent on the zoom level at which you request the data and will contain many artefacts.  Do everything you can to get vector data!

Without seeing the data, it is impossible to say why you are getting nothing at all, except that 1-bit is an odd choice - are you sure you didn't mean 1-byte?

Comment: No.. I'm sure that I used 1-bit Monochrome Threshold as an option. In addition, the minimum appropriate scale is 25.000, however I don't have any restriction at the maximum scale. Do I have to export WMS services as a map in a specify scale?

Comment: 1-bit is only either 0 or 1 (effectively boolean) so it's not impossible, just unusual.  I think you need to read up on WMS to understand how it works and what it delivers.  In brief: a WMS server renders raster tiles usually with a dimension of 256x256 pixels.  The whole Earth is zoom 0 and is a single tile.  Then each zoom level subdivides the Earth by powers of two.  Therefore, the higher the zoom the smaller the area covered by any one tile (whose size remains constant at 256 pixels).  This is great for web-maps but terrible for delivering vector data.